# Explicit Chebotarev in function fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K/\mathbb F_q(T)$ be a finite Galoisian extension of degree $d$ and $n\in\mathbb N$. Does one have a completely explicit bound on the number of irreducible $P\in\mathbb F_q[T]$ of degree $\le n$ that split totally in $K$ ($n\to+\infty$)? (I would like to have the two main terms of the asymptotic estimate)

Comment: V. K. Murty and J. Scherk, ‘Effective versions of the Chebotarev density theorem for function
fields’, Comp. Rend. Acad. Sci. Paris, Série I, 319 (1994), 523–528. I am surprised it doesn't show on a google search.

Comment: I already knew this article:https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k57326058/f532.item . But, I did not find the bound for the number of primes totally split.

Comment: Totally split should be the easiest case as it is just counting $\mathbb F_{q^n}$ points on the curve corresponding to the Galois closure of $K$ and dividing by the order of the Galois group, minus some lower-order terms. The worst part is writing down a formula for all the lower-order terms.

Comment: I edited the question a little bit.

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.

Comment: Theorem 1 or Theorem 2 in the article linked by Felipe Voloch with $C$ the conjugacy class of the identity element should be exactly what you need. There is only one main term - why do you think there should be two?

Comment: No precise reason to think there are more terms. I am just surprised that the third term is already bounded.